# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'home_list' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I red a lot about other similar topics and I can't find an answer in any of them.

in my page I have

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
     <script>
            angular.module('guest',[]);
       </script>
    <div class="well " ng-app="guest">
       <h2> My Homes List</h2>
       <% include partials/home_list %>
    </div>
</body>
```

In partials/home_list I have the following :

```
 <script src="/script/ctrl/guests/home_list"></script>
 <div ng-controller="home_list" ></div>
```

and finaly in /script/ctrl/guests/home_list I have :

```
angular.module('guest').controller('home_list', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
}]);
```

My module is well defined and not overwritten. I don't get why I'm getting this Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'home_list' is not a function, got undefined.

Comment: You can find out your problem, by this checklist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

Answer (score 0):

The answer : Only one ngApp directive can be used per HTML Document. Apparently declaring multiple ng-app result in a missdeclaration for the modules of the second ng-app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding this line to your main page

```
<script src="/script/ctrl/guests/home_list"></script>
```

in this way

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
     <script>
            angular.module('guest',[]);
       </script>
    <div class="well " ng-app="guest">
       <h2> My Homes List</h2>
       <% include partials/home_list %>
    </div>
    <script src="/script/ctrl/guests/home_list"></script>
</body>
```