# How to find a reason AngularJS "Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When AngularJS crashes with an error "**Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**" it's may be little bit challenging to find a reason why.

Here I want to make a kind of a "check list", what should you check when got an error

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. **Is file with 'MyCtrl' connected via html**? (check twice if you concat or uglify your files)

```js
<script src='path/to/controllers.js'></script>
```

2. **Is 'MyCtrl' defined correctly**?

There are a few patterns:

```js
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {...}])

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {...})

var MyCtrl = function ($scope) {...})
```

3. **Is 'MyCtrl' defined in right module?**
4. **Is "MyCtrl's" module added to app dependencies**?

```js
angular.module('app', ['app.sources']);
```

5. If you define your module **multiple** times, you should **define it in this order**:

   - First define should be like

```js
angular.module('app.sources', []);
```

(with **`[ ]`**)

- Subsequent defines should be like

```js
angular.module('app.sources');
```

(without **`[ ]`**)

**Important**: Declaration order is important - definition with **`[ ]`** should go first.

6. Check that **module** is **defined only once**.
   You may have forgotten to rename module after copy-paste. Check src for string like

```js
angular.module('app.sources', []);
```

7. **Check your** `'ng-app'`. Better to use only one of these with name like `ng-app='app'` (In other words do not define multiple unnamed ngApp directives)
8. Is your controller's syntax **correct for your AngularJS version**?

(There is a difference between definition in Angular **1.0.x** and **1.2.x** and higher. With Angular versions greater than **1.3.x**, you cannot declare a global constructor function and use it with ng-controller)

Comment: this saves my day "With the Angular upper than 1.3.x, you can not declare a global constructor function and use it with ng-controller", thanks

Comment: I checked all described steps including module, controller definition, priority, attachement in index.html and so forth. The problem persists ONLY in Firefox. Chrome shows no errors at the same page. What can be wrong ?

Comment: It's difficult to say why. May be chrome cached something? Anyway firefox provide more detailed errors than chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `ng-controller` with "controller as" syntax, be sure to check that the name of the controller is correct.

My case:

```
//controller register    
angular.module("myApp").controller("someController", SomeController)

//in my code
<div ng-controller="SomeController as vm"></div>
```

Notice that I used `ng-controller="SomeController as vm"`, where `SomeController` has a capital `S`. 
It should have been with a lowercase `s` because that's how I registered it.

So, check that your controller name is correct.