# multiple controller not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jsp

i am new to angular js. i write the code for perform multiple controller concept but it is not working .i dont know where i am doing wrong?

following code i am using

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="q">
<input type="number" ng-model="c">
<p>{{ q*c }}</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="newone">
<p>{{lastName|uppercase}}</p>

</div>




</body>


<script>
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope)
{
    $scope.q=10;
    $scope.c=5;

    });
</script>
<script src="control.js"></script>
</html>



**control.js**

var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('newone',function($scope){
    alert();
    $scope.firstName="Vinoth";
    $scope.lastName="Kumar";
    $scope.full=function()
    {
        return $scope.firstName+''+$scope.lastName;
    }

});
```

above code is not working  can any one help me to fix this

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: i think you need to create a route for the controller to associate an url with a html view and controller : interfaceApp.config(['$routeProvider',
   function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
         when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
         }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
         });
}]);

Comment: @AlainIb In this case there isn't any routing necessary. Just 1 HTML page...

Comment: In future, take a look for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797756/how-to-find-a-reason-angularjs-argument-myctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefin and you should know that chrome has a bug with showing errors in console (errors didn't show reason), then use firefox instead of chrome (for sometimes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In controller.js you don't need to declare the module again :)

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

change it to `var app=angular.module('myApp');`

Comment: can u explain what is the need for [ ] in declaration

Comment: Hey KVK it is used for DI(dependency injection) and allow you to add the dependency of other modules.