# Getting error - "Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mean-stack

Unable to figure out where I am making a mistake.
Tried following this without any luck - 
[How to find a reason AngularJS "Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797756/how-to-find-a-reason-angularjs-argument-myctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefin)

Here is my index.html file -

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head><title>Angular JS table sort and filter example </title>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
   <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/angular.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/angular-resource.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>   
   <style>  
     .odd {  
       background-color: antiquewhite;  
       color: #008b8b;  
     }  
     td th {  
       height: 30px;  
       min-width: 100px;  
     }  
     thead {  
       background-color: darkgray;  
       color: white;  
       height: 30px;  
     }  
   </style>  
 </head>  
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">  
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
     <h3>List students</h3>  
     <div class="container-fluid">  
       <pre>Click header link to sort, input into filter text to filter</pre>  
       <hr />  
       <table class="table table-striped">  
         <thead>  
           <tr>  
             <th>  
               <a href="" ng-click="order('name')">Name</a>  
             </th>  
             <th><a href="" ng-click="order('age')"> Age</a> </th>  
             <th><a href="" ng-click="order('gender')">Gender</a> </th>  
           </tr>  
         </thead>  
         <tbody>  
           <tr>  
             <td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" /></td>  
             <td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.age" /> </td>  
             <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.gender" /> </td>  
           </tr>  
           <tr ng-repeat="user in students | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:paginate| filter:search" ng-class-odd="'odd'">  
             <td>{{user.name}}</td>  
             <td>{{user.age}}</td>  
             <td>{{user.gender}}</td>  
           </tr>  
         </tbody>  
       </table>  
       <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
             max-size="5" boundary-links="true"  
             items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
       </pagination>  
     </div>  
   </div>  
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller.js file -

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);  
     app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {  
       $scope.predicate = 'name';  
       $scope.reverse = true;  
       $scope.currentPage = 1;  
       $scope.order = function (predicate) {  
         $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;  
         $scope.predicate = predicate;  
       };  
       $scope.students = [  
         { name: 'Kevin', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Laura', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Joy', age: 15, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Mary', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Peter', age: 95, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'Bob', age: 50, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'Erika', age: 27, gender: 'girl' },  
         { name: 'Patrick', age: 40, gender: 'boy' },  
         { name: 'Tery', age: 60, gender: 'girl' }  
       ];  
       $scope.totalItems = $scope.students.length;  
       $scope.numPerPage = 5;  
       $scope.paginate = function (value) {  
         var begin, end, index;  
         begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;  
         end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;  
         index = $scope.students.indexOf(value);  
         return (begin <= index && index < end);  
       };  
     });
```

Comment: Controller constructor function must be in passed in array `app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { //your controller code here}]);`

Comment: Did not work - Here is how controller.js looks now. Did I make a mistake?                                                                                                   var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);  
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       //mycontroller code here
     }]);

Comment: strangely enough, the code seems to work fine locally. I noticed you have 2 `ng-app`s declared in your html. you might need only one.

Comment: I agree with @danielepolencic - try to remove second `ng-app` attribute from your `body` tag, leave only with the `html` tag

Comment: It worked - @danielepolencic - Tips from Andrew plus you solved the error.  Last night I could not sleep as much as I wanted as it was in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has to do with how the app is initialised and the double `ng-app`. You can easily verify that by bootstrapping angularjs manually:

When you remove both `ng-app` and add the following snippet at the bottom at `controllers/controller.js`, your script works:

`angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});`

Comment: In addition to this I also had to apply changes mentioned by Andrew in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Controller constructor function must be passed in array

`app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) { 
        //your controller code here
    }
]);`