# AngularJS - ng-app not working if not emplty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this question may be a very very basic question of [Angular.JS](https://angularjs.org/).
May be nearly this question is asked in [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/) before, but I am unable to find the question, so I have to ask this question.

I am pretty new in [Angular.JS](https://angularjs.org/) and I am trying to create a basic form with Angular.JS which will validate an email address from given input.

What is working for me is-

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app="" name="myForm">
    Email:
    <input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="text">
    <span ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email">Not a valid e-mail address</span>
</form>
<p>Enter your e-mail address in the input field. AngularJS will display an errormessage if the address is not an e-mail.</p>
```

But what I am trying to give a name of my angular app like this- `ng-app="my_try_app"` so my code has been like this-

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<form ng-app="my_try_app" name="myForm">
    Email:
    <input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="text">
    <span ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email">Not a valid e-mail address</span>
</form>

<p>Enter your e-mail address in the input field. AngularJS will display an errormessage if the address is not an e-mail.</p>
```

And u are seeing it is not working.

So, my question is-

1. What is the way of giving my angular app a name?
2. Why in my case it is not working?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: you must define app for your view.

Comment: Can u please give me a detailed answer, please @hadiJZ

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it's explain few things about modules and controllers definitions http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at angulaJS doc below:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp
Basically, "ng-app" is used during Bootstrap Phase, It helps the angular to initializes your module.(Determines the boundary of HTML code which should be coming under angular influence.)

For example:
    
    Name: 
    
The ng-app directive tells AngularJS that the `<div>` element is the "owner" of an AngularJS application.
In the sample code mentioned, angularJS is configured to work in default mode.
Hence ng-app is optional, i.e is null/empty.

However if you wish to bootstrap your app/HTMl with ng-app="my_try_app", then can follow any of below

1. Define a angular controller either inside script tag or separate Js file & import using `<script src>` ,

   For eg. add below inside your HTML file

   ```
   <script>
   var app = angular.module('my_try_app', []);
   app.controller('myTryCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.text= "a@a.t.com";    
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. For larger apps, i,e with multiple views, bootstrap angular using..
   `angular.bootstrap(document,["my_try_app"]);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

you must define app for your view. like this.

```js
angular.module("my_try_app",[]);
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<form ng-app="my_try_app" name="myForm">
    Email:
    <input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="text">
    <span ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email">Not a valid e-mail address</span>
</form>

<p>Enter your e-mail address in the input field. AngularJS will display an errormessage if the address is not an e-mail.</p>
```

Comment: So, if I define a app name, it should be defined in JS file, right?

Comment: it is better if you defined in js file. but you can define it in script tag in html.

Comment: I am not asking that, is there any way of doing that in HTML all like other elements done in this code?