# angular service doesn't start

Tags: html, angularjs, web-services

I'm trying to write my first angular project. Until now, I created 3 files: index.html, index.js and service.js

**service.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.service('apiService', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.get = function() {
    return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects");
  };
  this.delete = function(id) {
    return $http.delete("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects/{id}", id);
  }
  this.post = function(data){
    return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects", data);
  }
}]);
```

**index.js**

```
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', 'apiService', function($scope, apiService) {
  var vm = this;
  var getData = apiService.get().success(function(data) {
    vm.data = data;
  }); 
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javavscript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javavscript" src="index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javavscript" src="service.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in ctrl.data">{{data.name}}</div>
  </div>

  </body></html>
```

and here is **my web.xml** :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>io.swagger.jaxrs.json;io.swagger.jaxrs.listing;io.swagger.api</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
   <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.PostReplaceFilter</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>api.version</param-name>
   <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
   <param-name>swagger.api.title</param-name>
   <param-value>Swagger Server</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
   <param-value>http://localhost:8080/api/v1</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <filter>
   <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>io.swagger.api.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   </web-app>
```

My problem is that my angular never starts!!! But I don't see any problem here and everything seems normal to me. I don't have any idea where the problem is

Comment: change this <html lang="en" ng-app="app">

Comment: Take a look at second point of my answer, perhaps it's helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36217211/930170

Comment: Is any errors in console? Please update the question if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try few things

1. Replace `ng-app="myApp"` with `ng-app="app"`
2. Module should be declared like this: `var app = angular.module('app', []);` (added empty dependencies - `[ ]`);
3. Change file's order in html

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="service.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Just because first definition of main module exist in `service.js`: `var app = angular.module('app');`

4. Also, modules order has mean. If you will faced an error like
   "**Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**", take a
   look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170), cause it has some explanations about such
   things, like definitions and orders errors
5. Added worked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23414/)

Comment: And one more answer that will not fix the issue. All of that has already been covered by Hasan.

Comment: Agree, you provided more details, maybe you want to mention that correct type `text/javascript` means a lot too.

Comment: @dfsq added one more case, take a look (number 2)

Comment: Now it's complete: `angular.module('app', [])` was one more important problems here.

Comment: var app = angular.module('app', []) this will not make it work too

Comment: I swear that it's not still working for me. I just posted my web.xml. Can you say please if the problem comes from this file? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

to

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
```

Comment: I swear that it's not still working for me. I just posted my web.xml. Can you say please if the problem comes from this file? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Swap the orders for these two js files and replace your js with this

```
          <script type="text/javascript" src="service.js"></script>  
          <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Order must be like this because app must be defined before controller

and html tag must

```
       <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
```

Comment: it will not work anyway, it's not enough, however you are closest to solution

Comment: I recommend you to set up demo http://plnkr.co/edit/ and see yourself what the problem is.

Comment: this will not work on plunker because we dont have yet <script type="text/javavscript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: You can set up plunker with Angular from CDN: http://plnkr.co/edit/OZoVbxpbQHPEDeOyaHcj?p=preview

Comment: I swear that it's not still working for me. I just posted my web.xml. Can you say please if the problem comes from this file? thanks!!!

Comment: print data in the getData method of controller