# Angular Controller cannot be found

Tags: angularjs

I know this has been asked but nothing answers my question.  I'm getting the error `Argument 'StoreController' is not a function, got undefined`

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/app.js"></script>
        <title>Let's Learn Angular!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
            <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
            <h2>${{store.product.price}}</h2>
            <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("store", []);
    app.controller("StoreController", function() {
        this.product = gem;
    });
    var gem = {
        name: "Dodecahedron",
        price: 2.95,
        description: "This is a 12 sided three-dimensional solid",
    };

})();
```

I've checked to make sure the path to `app.js` is correct.  I didn't quite understand how `$scope` was being implemented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) but I followed those instructions to no avail.  Angular works correctly outside of the `div` where I declare the controller.  I've gone through [this checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797756/how-to-find-a-reason-angularjs-argument-myctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefin/26797874#26797874) and followed the steps as best as I could understand.  My code is all copied from the CodeSchool angular.js course and I don't see any differences.  I'm using Angular 1.5

Comment: Why have you wrapped your app.js in a function?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Same, no errors [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1It6smxtj7oemqAvxqlJ?p=preview)

Comment: It shouldn't matter but I am a bit suspicious of the controller and app both being referenced as store, even though it ran for me.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too.  I tried changing one of the names to 'shop' and it didn't help.

Comment: And everyone that has the code working is using Angular 1.5?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure app.js is in resources? Typically this would be a path used for 3rd party things. Open up your developer tools and see if an error is being displayed and check the network tab to verify app.js is being loaded properly. I don't see any issues with the code. Update: and I copied and pasted your code and ran it locally without issue.

Comment: OK--at least I'm not crazy, but yes, that's the only error in the console and the path is definitely correct.