# Module 'App' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a simple web application using angularJS and I'm running into this issue I cannot resolve. Running my website I get this error in console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App
>   due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'App' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

But I'm sure I didn't misspell the module name or forgot to load it. Here's my code:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ui-notification', 'ngFileUpload']);

App.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    console.log("TEST");
}]);
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // TODO: routing
}]);

App.factory('file-uploader', ['Upload', function(Upload) {
    var uploadFile = function(file, callback) {
        var uploader;
        uploader = Upload.upload({
            url: 'SERVER URL' + '/upload-file',
            data: {
                image: file
            }
        });
        uploader.then(function(fileData) {
            return callback(null, fileData);
        });
        uploader.catch(function(error) {
            return callback(error, null);
        });
    };

    return uploadFile;
}]);
```

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="AUTHOR">
    <title>PROJECT NAME | Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body ng-class="location" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I've installed all the packages with bower...

Can someone please tell me where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you included the app somewhere in your html with `ng-app="App"`?

Comment: This checklist may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

Comment: @thepio sure, in my html i have html(ng-app="App")

Comment: Have you also made sure you have all the external resources available? Like `ngRoute` etc? I got your code to work fine in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxn9x9g4/ . I of course removed all the other depencies except `ngRoute`.

Comment: Your <script> line for angular itself is the first one you include?

Comment: @thepio i've updated my question to show you guys the html file

Comment: You are not including your own script with all the App stuff? Just add it above the `bower_components` scripts and you should be fine.

Comment: That's it! Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to add your own script, based on the HTML you provided. I only see `bower_components` stuff being included