# Controller not defined AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=CampaignsSettingsController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined) when I try to run my application.

```
Argument 'CampaignsSettingsController' is not a function, got undefined
```

My controller is defined here:

```js
// Called Second
var campaignsSettingsModule;
campaignsSettingsModule = angular.module('campaignsSettings');
campaignsSettingsModule.controller(
    'CampaignsSettingsController', [
        '$scope',
        '$window',
        'CampaignAdvancedSettings',
        function($scope, $window, CampaignAdvancedSettings) {
            // my controller code here
        }
    ]
);
```

And the `campaignSettings` module is called like this:

```js
// Called first
var modules = ['evApp', 'campaignsSettings'];

for (var i = 0, length = modules.length; i < length; i++) {
    angular.module(modules[i], []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[').endSymbol(']}');
    });
}
```

The order in which these files are called (dunno if it makes a difference) is indicated above the code.

What would be the reason for getting the undefined error? Where can I start looking into solving this problem. I've read through various answers here, but I still can't get it fixed.

Comment: Check with this checklist:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

Comment: As far as I am always doing custom modules are always injected on the second of param of `angular.module('thisModuleName', ['inject', 'your', 'modules', 'here'])` also, dont wrap it in for loop. It looks weird.

Comment: By the way I wrote a personal template/boiler plate for angularjs this might help you construct your angular project easier. Here. https://github.com/jofftiquez/angular-app-starter-pack

Comment: Seems like a dumb question, but have you remembered to include the JS file on your index file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

**From:**

```
campaignsSettingsModule = angular.module('campaignsSettings');
```

**To:**

```
campaignsSettingsModule = angular.module('campaignsSettings',[]);
```