# index Ctrl is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey could someone answer this for me as it is really wrecking my head.

I am getting an error stating that the controller is not a function and got defined. Now I understand this but I really can't see why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="kachicode">
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJs Gmail</title>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="routeCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/config/route.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body  id="backImg">
     <div ui-view></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

So this is my page and the routing is working fine. Basically my problem is in the routeCtrl.js file saying the function is not defined:

```
var app = angular.module('kachicode', []);
app.controller('indexCtrl', function indexCtrl($scope){
    $scope.greeting ="hey seam";
    $scope.goTo = function() {
        console.log("clicking");
    }
});
```

This my home file that is being loaded in the uiview

```
<div ng-controller="indexCtrl as ctrl">

{{ctrl.greeting}}


</div>




angular.module('kachicode', ['ui.router'])


.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    'use strict';


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {

            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'



        })


        .state('about', {

            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'kachicode/about.html'

        })

        .state('contact', {

            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'kachicode/contact.html'


        });


});
```

this is my route file

Ok no now. I've checked to see am I loading the file correctly and made sure that it is attaching to kachicode which is defined in ng-app = "kachicode". These are the common reasons for this problem as per the stackoverflow forums but mine still isn't working. Could someone help me and I'll know forever more how to fix it?

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you include the (relevant) code from route.js? And why are you using both ng-route AND ui.router?

Comment: Sorry I was just doing that just now...... I haven't included in the controller and controlleras to the states because my understanding is adding the ngcontroller to the div would be ok.

Comment: is your code getting minified?

Comment: no..... I literally just set this up and quickly tried to set up the routing and then couldn\t go not further

Comment: Check yourself with this list of possible reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your app twice, once in your routeCtrl.js:

```
var app = angular.module('kachicode', []);
```

And again in your route.js:

```
angular.module('kachicode', ['ui.router'])
```

Either remove the second parameter from your route.js (and add the dependency to your routeCtrl.js's app), or change your setup

The solution, based on the order of loading of your scripts (first routeCtrl.js, then route.js) do this in your routeCtrl.js:

```
var app = angular.module('kachicode', ["ui.router]);
```

And this in your route.js:

```
angular.module('kachicode')
```

Though make sure that you load in the angular-ui-router **before** your routeCtrl.js

Comment: It still won\t work. I'm still getting the error not a function

Comment: this is *mostly* correct;  you may want to be more explicit about the actual solution to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks i got it working..... it was a little more than that but you set me on my way....... The other piece was that the controller I was using I was trying to call in the index page but I wasn't on it anymore as I had changed states so it was coming up as undefined because that controller wasn't linked to the current state....... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Below is the recommended way to define a controller.

```
var app = angular.module('kachicode', ['ui.router']);

 //no need to write function indexCtrl() -- see below
 //also use the an array to inject you dependencies in the controller -> this syntax is good if you plan on minifying your code

 app.controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){ 


    $scope.greeting ="hey seam";

    $scope.goTo = function() {

    console.log("clicking");

 }

}]);
```

You also seem to be creating you app twice. In route.js, I would remove this line:

```
angular.module('kachicode', ['ui.router'])
```

and simply do:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

'use strict';


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider

    .state('home', {

        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'

    })


    .state('about', {

        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'kachicode/about.html'

    })

    .state('contact', {

        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'kachicode/contact.html'


    });


 });
```

I hope that helps fix your problem