# Angular js simple login form error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to the angular js. I have created a simple login form and while loading page gives error. I am unable to understand the error and don't know how to resolve this error. My code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- The above 2 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Digital World</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="digitalWorld">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="loginController">
        <form ng-submit="login()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p>{{myTxt}}</p>

    </div>

<script>
    //var app = angular.module("myLogin", []);
    /*app.controller("loginController", function($scope) {
        $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
        $scope.myFunc = function () {
            $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
        }
    });*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives some error like this::

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=digitalWorld&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DdigitalWorld%0AG%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A186%0Ab%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A251%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A494%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A117%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A331%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488%0Aeb%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A249%0Ayc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463%0Ayc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274%0AZd%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A294%3A192%0Ab%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A175%3A62%0AIf%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A365%0AHf%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A314%0A
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js
Line 6
```

a) How can I resolve this?

b) I am unable to understand the console error. How to debug issues like this, is there any tool or something for debugging?
Can somebody please help as I am new to Angular Js

Comment: For development purposes, use non-minified version of angular, change `angular.min.js` for `angular.js` in your script src.

Comment: do you have this error with your js code commented ? Because it seems you should declare `var app = angular.module("digitalWorld", []);` instead of `var app = angular.module("myLogin", []);`

Comment: @D555 - the error clearly mentions that angular injector cannot find `digitalWorld` which you have used in html `ng-app="digitalWorld"` in your script replace `var app = angular.module("myLogin", []);` with `var app = angular.module("digitalWorld", []);`

Comment: If you follow the link in the error you will end up at https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=digitalWorld which tells you that the module "digitalWorld" is not available

Comment: you appear to be using `ng-app="digitalWorld"` but your angular app is `myLogin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What happens**:

Basically angular can't find module definition (`digitalWorld`).

Here: `nomod` (no module) `%3Fp0%3D` `digitalWorld` (module's name)`%0AG`
and after that you have link to angularjs documentation which lead you to your problem explanation ([click](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=digitalWorld&p1=%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DdigitalWorld%0AG%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:24:186%0Ab@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:23:251%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:23:494%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:117%0An@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:331%0Ag@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488%0Aeb@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:41:249%0Ayc%2Fc@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:463%0Ayc@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:20:274%0AZd@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:83%0A@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:294:192%0Ab@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:175:62%0AIf@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:35:365%0AHf%2Fd@http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:35:314%0A)).

**How to fix**:

you should define app's name in html:

```
ng-app="digitalWorld"
```

And app (module) with same name in js:

```
angular.module("digitalWorld", []); //instead of "myLogin"
```

P.S.: you can define module with same name multiple times, but at first time it's should be , `angular.module("digitalWorld", []);` and all other times `angular.module("digitalWorld");` - without `[]`.

**How to prevent in future**:

In case of such or similar errors, just check with this list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

There're list of most common mistakes with angular's modules definitions.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but still same error.

Comment: @D555 Great job, keep going! ;)

Comment: @D555 and don't forget to accept the answer ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To debug :

click on the link : [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?...][1]

In fact it says :

> Module 'digitalWorld' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

check the module name and declaration

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body ng-app="digitalWorld" ng-controller="loginController">
<div class="container">
    <form ng-submit="login()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p>{{myTxt}}</p>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('digitalWorld', []);
    appEnq.controller("loginController", function($scope)
    {
         $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
         $scope.myFunc = function () 
         {
             $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
         }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

You have define one(myLogin) ng-app and used different one(digitalWorld)