# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hate to ask this question b/c there are so many similar to it but I have wasted 5 hours today trying to solve what is causing this issue.  My app runs perfect in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 11 or Edge, I receive a `SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' MapService.js (43,55)`, `SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' MainController.js (299,44)`, and `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined` errors.  My code is structured as follows :

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="SS" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl" >

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    <script src="src/SS/DefaultConfigs.js"></script>
    <script src="src/SS/MapService.js"></script>
    <script src="src/SS/MainController.js"></script>
....
```

index.js

```
angular
    .module("SS", ["ngMaterial", "angular-intro"])
        .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider) {
            "use strict";
            $mdIconProvider
                .defaultIconSet("./assets/svg/settings.svg", 128)
                .icon("clipboard", "./assets/svg/clipboard_48px.svg", 48)
                .icon("close", "./assets/svg/close_48px.svg", 48);
                ....

            $mdThemingProvider.theme("default")
                .primaryPalette("blue")
                .dark();
    });
```

MainController.js

```
angular
    .module('SS')

    .controller('MainController', function($interval, $location, $mdDialog, $mdSidenav, $mdToast, $scope, DefaultConfigs, MapService) {
        'use strict';
        var animationRunner;
        ....

        /* Snippet of code surrounding where 2nd error supposedly is */
        var updateMap = function() {
            MapService.updateCurrentRotation();
            MapService.updateCurrentZoom();
            MapService.updateCurrentCenter();
            $scope.setVisibility();
        };
        // line below is line 299
        $scope.setVisibility = function(ind=$scope.currentId, prev=$scope.prevId) {
            var temp = MapService.layers;
            if (layerExists(prev)) {
                temp[prev].setVisible(false);
            }
            if (layerExists(ind)) {
                temp[ind].setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        /* End snippet of code surrounding where 2nd error supposedly is */
    })

    .directive('ngRightClick', function($parse) {
        ....
    });
```

MapService.js

```
angular
    .module('SS')

    .service('MapService', function($location, DefaultConfigs) {
        'use strict';
        this.map = null;
        this.layers = [];

        /* Snippet of code surrounding where 1st error supposedly is */
        this.createProjection = function() {
            this.proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
                code: 'EPSG:0000',
                units: 'pixels',
                extent: [0, 0, 8192, 8192]
            });
        };

        /* next line is line 43 */
        this.createLayer = function(ind, isVisible=false, counter=1) {
            var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                preload: Infinity,
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                    url: this.baseURL + ind + '/{z}-{y}-{x}.png',
                    projection: this.proj,
                    wrapX: false,
                    attributions: [this.tileAttribution]
                }),
                transitionEffect: 'resize',
                visible: isVisible
            });
            imageLayer.id = counter;
            imageLayer.playerId = parseInt(ind, 10);

            return imageLayer;
        };
        /* End snippet of code surrounding where 1st error supposedly is */
    });
```

I have checked JSLint to check for errors in my code but nothing was found that fixed the IE error.  I am not using a global controller declaration, I have not called ng-app twice, I believe my javascript calls are in the proper order, I am not overriding my SS module, I haven't found any comma or bracket errors.  I am stumped.  I have read through so many others solutions and I have checked all the options on the checklist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797756/how-to-find-a-reason-angularjs-argument-myctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefin/26797874#26797874).

Does the fact that those two `)` errors keep showing and that this is only occurring in IE provide a hint as to my problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your issue is the default params:

```
ind=$scope.currentId, prev=$scope.prevId
...
isVisible=false, counter=1
```

This is an [ES6 feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), and according to this [compatability chart](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), IE11 and Edge only have partial support for ES6. It's not supported until Edge 14.

You can either change your code, use a transpiler, use an [ES6 shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim), or (my favorite) drop support for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue !  I assumed there was a compatability issue somewhere but wow ... default params just feels so normal I didn't think that this would be the cause.  Unfortunately I need to test this project back to IE9 ...